# gitosis equivalent for subversion?

Tags: svn, git

Is there an equivalent of gitosis for subversion? As in a wrapper package that allows ssh access via ssh keys, with everyone using the one ssh user?

Answer (score 1):

I've [written one](https://github.com/larsks/svnbiosis).  It's not particularly documented or tested at this point, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Lars' python scripts work for me too, after some manual setup of "svn" user, including:

- manual editing of /Users/svn/.ssh/authorized_keys,
- the chmods to the commit hook files that Lars mentions in his readme,
- updating the "svn" user's PATH to include location of svnbiosis-serve script.

I'm using Mac OS X, so for "svn" local user setup I used the "dscl" tool according to http://blog.ardes.com/2008/5/19/git-hosting-with-leopard, and then just referenced my /Users/git/.ssh/* setup for /Users/svn/.ssh/* setup and as a sanity check.

(Wanted to post this as a comment to Lars' solution, but serverfault is not letting me ... or at least not letting in an obvious way)

Comment: I believe that new users are not able to leave comments...but in any case, I'm glad to know it's working out for someone!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a wrapper like gitosis or gitolite, which both use "[forced command](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#22858)" for declaring their wrapper.

svnserver itself allow for a [ssh configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks).
And as this [SF answer illustrates](https://serverfault.com/questions/45321/user-directory-permissions-on-ssh-server), thant doesn't prevent you to add your own "forced command" ssh wrapper.